# Vim: <C-b> move cursor to the last line of screen (if the cursor is not at that position)

Tags: vim, neovim

I want `<C-b>` move cursor to the last line of screen if the cursor is not at the last line, otherwise, scroll page down.

ps: I know there is an internal variable for cursor position, I'd be grateful if you tell me where to find variables like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about "the last line in the **window**".

You can create an `<expr>` mapping to achieve that:

```
nnoremap <expr> <c-b> line('.')==line('w$')?'<c-f>':'L'
```

- It checks if the current line is the last line in the current window
- True: `<c-f>` next page, you can also change it into `<c-d>`
- False: `L`, go to the last line in the current window.